# Isolating search terms from a URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, url

I have an array of ugly, complex URL strings and I want to separate out specific search terms that people have typed such as "example" from `http://google.com/search/things/q="example"`.

Occasionally there is a search that has a `+` separating terms and at the end of the user-specified query is a `&`.

I have no idea where to start, even after plenty of Googling around. Any help to get me started would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `http://google.com/search/things/q="example"` valid or is it supposed to be `http://google.com/search/things?q="example"`? The second is valid. The first I haven't seen before.

Comment: The second one. First was a typo on my part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)
```

Example:

```
>> CGI.parse(URI.parse("http://google.com/?foo=bar&baz=hello").query)
=> {"foo"=>["bar"], "baz"=>["hello"]}
```

Remember to require `cgi` and `uri` first, of course.

Comment: Do I need to require cgi and uri if I'm running a rails app?

Comment: Rails automatically loads both of these libraries via rack. So no :-)

Comment: Thank you sir. Such a big help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this: http://codefol.io/posts/9-How-Does-Rack-Parse-Query-Params-With-parse-nested-query

If you're using a Rack-based framework (like Sinatra or Rails), you already have this for free.

Answer (score 0):

The [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/) gem, and Ruby's own [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module, can both do what you want, or you could pretty easily roll your own.

Addressable::URI is very powerful and conforms to the [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) spec. Here's a sample of its use from inside PRY:

```
[9] (pry) main: 0> uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://google.com/search/things?q="example"')
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x80ec33a0 URI:http://google.com/search/things?q="example">
[10] (pry) main: 0> uri.query
=> "q=\"example\""
[11] (pry) main: 0> uri.query_values
=> {"q"=>"\"example\""}
```

Particularly useful is the `query_values` method which returns a hash.

You can easily write something that does the same though:

```
Hash['http://google.com/search/things?q="example"'.split('?').last.split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }]
=> {"q"=>"\"example\""}
```

The advantage to Addressable::URI and URI is they offer a lot of other functionality to manipulate URLs without you having to do so.